# How to check if a React Element was derived from a styled component?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have the following React Element called `cloned`:

```
const SpacingNew = props => {
  const cloned = React.cloneElement(props.children, { ...props });
  ...
}
```

I want to use the `isStyledComponent` function form the styled-components library to check if it is/was a styled component - how to do this?

```
const SpacingNew = props => {
  const cloned = React.cloneElement(props.children, { ...props });
  if (!isStyledComponent(cloned)) {
    return styled(cloned)``;
  }
}
```

the above code returns an error:

> Cannot create styled-component for component: [object Object]

Comment: Did you try checking before cloning?

Comment: This won't work because `props.children` is an element, not a component.

Comment: I would recommend checking a standard component first

Comment: Not sure I understand (?)